# str_replace Replacing same occurence of string as many times as it founds it

Tags: php, string

I am trying to replace some strings from an array with other strings, just that if the PHP intepretor finds the same string again it will apply the values to replace as tp the same string as many times the string is in the array. For example:

```
$html = 'first
         first
         second
         third
         third';
$array = array('first', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'third');
foreach ($array as $elem) {
  $html = str_replace($elem, $elem.' | added', $html);
}
var_dump($html); //will result

string 'first | added | added

             first | added | added

             second | added

             third | added | added

             third | added | added' (length=158)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
string 'first | added

             first | added

             second | added

             third | added

             third | added' (length=158)
```

Comment: `foreach (array_unique($array) as $elem) {`

Comment: @AbraCadaver That is not a solution, because I don;t want them unique.even if it not unique I want that string added.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you are telling it to.

Comment: @AbraCadaver so how can I get the expected output.

Comment: Not with `str_replace`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71530/discussion-between-user3467855-and-abracadaver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `preg_replace`:

```
foreach($array as $elem) {
    $html = preg_replace("/$elem(?! \| added)/", "$0 | added", $html);
}
```

Replace each item if it is not already followed by `| added`.  You could use `$elem` instead of `$0`.  There might be a better regex but I am intermediate not wizard.

Comment: Please come a bit in chat.